# Should I be using database ID's as Elastic ID's

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic and starting to sync my database tables into elastic indexes. I have started by using the table ID(UUID) as the elastic id, but I am starting to wonder if this is a mistake in terms of performance or flexibility in the long term? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I use the same technique and it works fine with me. Is it causing any problems with you?

Comment: If you don't need to query term(or delete) by table id, I suggest use elastic generate ID,  the generate ID can keep data more balance and don't need to check the ID on index(check if exist).

Comment: I have not had any problems to date, but was just chasing if anyone else had seen issues. The only thing I can think of atm is that I will be using ids for these tables with uuid but other tables which use traditional ids would not work, so there would be consistency issues.. not a big deal though I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this approach should actually be a best practice. When you **update** data in your ES index from the (changed) DB, you can address the document **directly**.

It has worked great for us to use the `_bulk` update API, which requires an explicit id per item.

On every change on the DB side, we enqueue change notifications, the changed object gets JSON-serialized and sent to ES, asynchronously, and in larger batches. *That* is making a huge performance difference. *Search* performance, on the other side, does not depend on the length of the `_id` AFAIK, not even when you look up by `_id`. So your DB UUID should be just fine. Especially since `_id`s can be alphanumeric, they are not limited to just numbers.

Having a 1:1 relationship via `_id` between the ES result and your system of record (I assume that's what your DB is for) is advantageous also for transparency purposes. In any case, you want to store the database ID as some field, ideally indexed, at least, to help you understand *where that document came from*.

So, rather than creating your own ID field, you may as well use the built-in `_id` field right away, with your DB-supplied data.